# Find the essential spectrum $\sigma_e(T)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a complex, separable, infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. Given an operator $T\in\mathcal{B(H)}$ and $\pi:\mathcal{B(H)}\rightarrow\mathcal{B(H)}/\mathcal{K(H)}$ the canonical quotient map, we define the essential spectrum of $T$ by $\sigma_e(T):=\sigma(\pi(T))$.

Let $\{e_n\}$ be the orthonormal basis for $\mathcal{H}$ and $\{\alpha_n\} \in \ell^{\infty}$.

Define $Te_n=\alpha_n e_n$.

Find the essential spectrum $\sigma_e(T)$ of the operator $T$.

What I've done:

I showed that $\sigma_e(T)\subseteq\sigma(T)$.

Also, I know that by Putnam-Schecheter, we have $\sigma(T)= \sigma_e \cup \Omega$, where $\Omega$ consists of some bounded components for the resolvent$\rho (\pi (T))$ and a sequence of isolated points in $\rho(\pi(T))$ converging to $\sigma_e(T)$.

Now I'm not sure how to continue. I think I need to use compactness at some point.

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try to compute the ordinary spectrum first. You can do that by calculating $(T-z)^{-1}$ explicitly. Then for $z$ in the spectrum try to construct an operator $S$ such that $S(T-z)-1$ and $(T-z)S-1$ are compact (you can think about finite rank first; it may be handy in the full solution that compact operator may be approximated by finite rank operators).

There exists also a more direct way which requires additional knowledge. The essential spectrum can be related to the notion of a Fredholm operator and its index. In your case it is fairly easy to figure out when $T-z$ is Fredholm, provided that you know required definitions.

Comment: I have that $\sigma(T) = \overline{(\alpha_n)}$. But I'm a little lost on constructing $S$. Could you give me some suggestions? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Suppose that $\alpha$ is an isolated point of the spectrum such that there exist only finitely many $n$ such that $\alpha_n=\alpha$. Put $Se_n=(\alpha_n -\alpha)^{-1} e_n$ for $n$ such that $\alpha_n=\alpha$, $Se_n=0$ otherwise. Can you see that this works?

Comment: When you defined $Se_n= (\alpha_n - \alpha )^{-1} e_n$ don't we have $\alpha_n - \alpha=0$, so $ (\alpha_n - \alpha )^{-1}$ is undefined? Did you mean the other way around?

Comment: Also, may I ask why such isolated point exists? Thank you!

Comment: Concerning your first comment: there is a typo in mine, I wanted to write "for $n$ such that $\alpha_n \neq \alpha$. Concerning your second comment: such isolated point is not guaranteed to exist, but I wanted to indicate how to deduce that any such point is not in the essential spectrum (although it is in the spectrum). As for the question whether the converse statement is also true, I am not sure how to proceed without invoking different characterizations of the essential spectrum.

Comment: Sorry I still don't see where the argument is going. Why do we need to show $S(T-Z)^{-1}-1$ and $(T-Z)^{-1}S-1$ are compact? Also, is $z \in \sigma(T)$ right?

Comment: I made a typo in my original answer (sorry, I was writing during night on a smartphone). I meant $S(T-z)-1$ and $(T-z)S-1$ not $S(T-z)^{-1}-1$ and $(T-z)^{-1}S-1$. Let $\alpha$ be as in my comment (and $z= \alpha$). Then $S(T-\alpha)e_n$ and $(T-\alpha)S e_n$ are both equal to $e_n$ if $\alpha_n \neq 0$ and equal to $0$ otherwise. Therefore $S(T-\alpha)-1$ and $(T-\alpha)S-1$ are both finite rank operators (their ranges are spanned by $e_n$ with $n$ such that $\alpha_n = \alpha$), in particular compact. Now reducing modulo compact operators we find that the equivalence class of $S$ is

Comment: the inverse of the equivalence class of $T-\alpha$ in $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)/ \mathcal K (\mathcal H)$. Hence $\alpha$ is not in the essential spectrum, directly from the definition you gave. On the other hand it is in the spectrum, by the choice of $\alpha$. What this result suggests is that we could look at three different cases for $\alpha$ in the spectrum: (i) isolated points of finite multiplicity, (ii) isolated points of infinite multiplicity, (iii) accumulation points. So far I showed that the first class is not in the essential spectrum.

Comment: Now suppose that $\alpha$ is a point of infinite multiplicty. Thus there exists infinitely many indices $n_i$ such that $(T-\alpha) e_{n_i}=0$. Therefore for any bounded operator $S$ we have $(S(T-\alpha)-1)e_{n_i}=-e_{n_i}$ from which you can deduce that $S(T-\alpha)-1$ is not compact. It follows that the equivalence class of $T-{\alpha}$ is not invertible. So points in the second class are in fact in the essential spectrum.

Comment: Next consider a point $\alpha$ of the third class. Then there exists an increasing sequence of indices $n_i$ such that $\alpha_{n_i} \to \alpha$. Note that $e_{n_i}\to 0$ weakly. Now $(T-\alpha)e_{n_i} = (\alpha_{n_i}-\alpha)e_{n_i} \to 0$ in norm, so for any $S$ also $S(T-\alpha)e_{n_i} \to 0$ in norm. But then $(S(T-\alpha)-1)e_{n_i} \to 0$ weakly, but not in norm. Therefore $S(T-\alpha)-1$ is not compact and the analysis is completed as in previous point, the conclusion being that accumulation points also lie in the essential spectrum. Sorry for confusing you!

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! The proof is very clear now! Just one very minor question: in (ii), why does $S(T-\alpha)-1$ being non-compact imply that $S(T-\alpha)$  is not compact?

Comment: I have not written that $S(T-\alpha)$ is not compact. What is needed here is that $S(T-\alpha)-1$ is not compact, which means that the equivalence class of $S$ is not the inverse of the equivalence class of $T-\alpha$ in $\mathcal B (\mathcal H) / \mathcal K (\mathcal H)$. It is certainly useful to know an example solved by an explicit calculation as here, but it is worth knowing also about another tool: Atkinson's theorem. It states that $z \in \sigma_{\mathrm{ess}}(T)$ if and only if $T-z$ is not a Fredholm operator. I suggest trying to solve the exervise also with this criterion.